# Accessing Image-element URL in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a number of <image> elements in my SVG. I want to add an onclick handler to them that accesses the image URL associated with the specific node, but I can't find the field name in the DOM documentation. If it was HTML then I would be accessing this.src, but the SVG DOM is clearly different -- I can't find any relevant documentation on this.

Added clarification: if I have something like
`<image xlink:href="http://example.jpg" onclick="code">` then I need the 'code' to access the image URL for the current node.

Answer (score 1):

OK, both of the following seem to work, although I'm not sure which is recommended:

`onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('xlink:href'),'_blank');"`

`onclick="window.open(this.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href'), '_blank');"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use handlers for SVG in `<object>` tag:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="picture.svg">
  <img src="picture.png" alt="">
</object>
```

Comment: That's not what I need to do. My SVG includes lots of JPG thumbnails in rect elements, using image elements. I want to add "onclick=..." handlers on each one that accesses the current image-file URL (to view in a different tab). I don't want to hand-code the image-file URL on each onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

SVG DOM properties have one extra trick because many can be animated: add an extra `.baseVal` (for the non-animated value) to the property name. In the case of `href`, you can leave off the `xlink:` part.

```
onclick="window.open(this.href.baseVal, '_blank');"
```